# Kotlin: Interface whereby the implementor must be a data class?

Tags: kotlin, data-class

Is there an Interface that I can extend or some other way to create an Interface whereby the implementing class must be a data class? It would be useful to have access to the data class API methods such as copy().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, *copy* method have unique number of parameters for every data class, so it's useless to have such interface. If all your data classes have same field - just create and implement common interface.

Answer (score -2):

So I'm going to preface my answer by saying I don't have experience with Kotlin, but I have plenty of Java experience which as I understand it is similar, so unless Kotlin has a feature that helps do what you want that Java doesn't, my answer might still apply.

If I understand correctly, basically what you're trying to do is enforce that whatever class implements your interface X, must also be a subtype of Y.

My first question would be Why would you want to do this? Enforcing that X only be implemented by subtypes of Y is mixing interface and implementation, which the exact opposite of what interfaces are for.

To even enforce this, you would have to have X extend the interface of Y, either implicitly or explicitly. Since in Java (and presumably Kotlin), interfaces cannot extend objects, you have two options:

1) extend the INTERFACE of data, if it exists (which I don't think it does given what I've been reading about data classes. It sounds more like a baked in language feature than just a helpful code object)

2) Add to your interface the exact method signatures of the methods you want out of data classes. BY doing this, you've gained two things: First, you get your convenience methods whenever a data class implements your interface, and second, you still have the flexibility that interfaces are meant to provide, because now even non-data classes *can* implement your interface if you need them to, they just have to be sure to define the data classes interface methods manually.

Comment: He is asking specifically about `data` classes which have built-in functionality that I am guessing he wants to ensure is active.

Comment: I won't downvote, but I think you should remove this answer, since it's way off-base.

Comment: Could you explain why you think it's "way off-base"? I started off with a disclaimer that I'm not familiar with Kotlin specifics, but the point I was trying to make is general across languages. Don't mix interface and implementation. That's just a good rule.

Comment: You are off base because the question is about a specific feature in Kotlin that does not exist in Java. The accepted answer is correct. Your answer, although you do have a valid point about inheritance, has nothing to do with the question and ads no value in this context.